# How to connect Azure Linux VM via Azure DevOps pipelines using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How to connect Linux vm using PowerShell script via pipeline. My SSH (.pem) file is stored in Library in secure file folder.

This PowerShell script I'm trying to pass the AZ CLI.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/obn2Y.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrOQh.png

Comment: In pipeline, unable to use powershell connect linux Azure VM with .pem file, but there is another way, see my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to connect Azure Linux VM via Azure DevOps pipelines using
> PowerShell

**The answer is yes**, but [only support HTTP/HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops).

I notice you mentioned .pem file, I think you want to use powershell to connect to your linux VM via .pem file? If yes, **then the answer to your question is NO.**

If you are trying to use this command:

`ssh -i <private key file> <user name of VM>@<VM IP address>`

The pipeline will refuse to allocate Pseudo-terminal.

---

As you know, even you connect to linux VM via powershell, you still run bash after connect to target linux VM.

So there is another way to achieve:

Using [SSH Deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops) to connect to target Azure liunx VM:

[image]

This is my YAML definition:

```
trigger:
- none

pool: VMAS

steps:
- task: SSH@0
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: 'SSH_To_Remote_VM'
    runOptions: 'inline'
    inline: 'ls'
    readyTimeout: '20000'
```

And my VM's NetWork setting:

[image]